# Why is a set comprehension slower than set() with a list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, set

I've been doing some benchmarking of Python code and have noticed a strange thing:

```
$ python -m timeit '{x**2 for x in range(10_000)}'
100 loops, best of 3: 3.3 msec per loop

$ python -m timeit 'set([x**2 for x in range(10_000)])'
100 loops, best of 3: 3.21 msec per loop
```

Why is a set comprehension slower than using the `set()` function with a list comprehension, which creates an intermediate list? I'm using Python 3.6.6.

Comment: I don't get the same result https://gist.github.com/NotTheEconomist/f090333b9171c50b4e86d6dea25f26a9

Comment: Yea now that I actually run the code from the question, I get the set comprehension being faster as well.

Comment: @user3483203 off-topic, but I actually often forget that I can separate digits with underscores in numeric literals. I would have done `int(1e4)` but this is obviously much better :)

Comment: Building a set whose size you know ahead of time is probably faster than not knowing when the last item is added. That could more than compensate for the time it takes to build the list.

Comment: `10_000`? Really? Where is that syntax coming from? Is that documented?

Comment: BTW, 3.3 msec and 3.21 msec seems like no difference to me. You should test it several times and see the deviation. This is probably just random.

Comment: @zvone https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0515/